# Como obter o número de telefone via facebook API

Tags: facebook

Estou implementando login via facebook em meu site e parece que não é mais possível obter o número de telefone do usuário, mesmo com a sua autorização.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

Esse post é de 2011. Pelo que entendi, é uma funcionalidade que existia e foi removida para que fosse aperfeiçoada a maneira pela qual o usuário é informado que o aplicativo vai extrair essa informação e que nas próximas semanas isso seria reabilitado.

Não encontrei mais nada a respeito. Pergunto: não é mesmo possível obter o celular do usuário que autorize isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felizmente/Infelizmente não é mais possível pegar o telefone do usuário via API.

Ano passado fiz esta pergunta para a Luz Caballero, Facebook Developer Advocate, na PHP Conference Argentina 2013 e ela disse "não há nenhuma maneira de recuperar o número de telefone do usuário através da API. Este foi um breve recurso, mas foi retirado pouco depois".

Comment: Pelo aviso (2011!) parece que a remoção era pra ser algo temporário: "We’ll be working to launch these updates as soon as possible, and will be *temporarily disabling* this feature [...] We look forward to re-enabling this [...]." Você consegue com o seu contato ao menos um link para alguma informação mais recente e, principalmente, definitiva?

Comment: @LuizVieira procurarei o cartão dela e ver se ela me responde por e-mail com algum link ou mais alguma informação e posto aqui.